# How to confirm the correlation between independent variables and dependent variable when Pseudo-R² is low?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, pseudo-r-squared

I have a logistic regression with 10 independent variables. I want that one of these independent variables is correlated with the dependent variable, others are covariants. In this regression model, p value of this variable is <0.05. However, Pseudo-R² (McFadden) of this regression is very low (<0.03). Can it prove this correlation? I also tried the ranktermtest function, p value is <0.05.

Comment: What do you mean when you write “correlation”? The typical way to examine for a correlation would be to find the correlation between two variables, not to run a logistic regression with additional features. This doesn’t make your approach wrong for answering your question, but it does leave me wondering what your question is.

Comment: @Dave I want to control the variation in the covariates, so I run a logistic regression. Is the method right? I want to check if a disease is associated with another disease, and many researches use logistics regression.

Comment: And you get that the disease, controlling for the covariates, is associated with the other disease, right?

Comment: @Dave This is my assumption, so I want to check it with this regression model.

Comment: What size is the key regression coefficient? It is entirely possible to find a significant relationship between two variables even when the independent variable has low effect size/low explanatory power. Significance and effect size are not the same thing. So, your results suggest that your key predictor variable is related to your outcome, but only weakly.

Comment: @Sointu The OR of this independent variable is 2.01. Is this relationship strong?

Comment: I don't typically use ORs, so I'm not sure, but it is my understanding that that would correspond to an effect size between small and medium.